# Лейаут, проблема с перекрытием элементов

Tags: android, android-layout

Есть вот такой лейаут:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="250dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dip"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/boxbg"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="22dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingTop="2dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/bg"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bg"
        android:text="text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/bg"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bg"
        android:text="time"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="5dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1" >

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Когда LinearLayout становится достаточно широким он перекрывает собой TextView и идет дальше вниз. Как сделать иначе? Что бы LinearLayout не перекрывал собой тестовое поле а доходил до границ экрана вместе с ним и потом шел вниз как сейчас.

на картинке описано то как должно быть.
[image]

Comment: в смысле перекрывает? Сдвигает за пределы экрана? 
Дак вы задайте чтобы он был слева от текствью, а текствью строго справа от парента? Или не прокатывает так?

Comment: Да за пределы. Не прокатывало(

Comment: оффтоп: странно у вас везде конечно написано @+id/bg. По сабжу попробую сейчас посмотреть)

Comment: копепаст) сейчас это не важно

Comment: Всеравно перекрывает(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать так, но тут придется еще все помещать в один LinearLayout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bg2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="#009ACD"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="22dip"
            android:paddingTop="2dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="В каждом из нас слишком много винтов, колес и клапанов, чтобы мы могли судить друг о друге по первому впечатлению или по двум-трем внешним признакам" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="80"
            android:background="#551A8B"
            android:text="time"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

</RelativeLayout>

В итоге получаем такое: [Скрин](http://iscr.ru/1339740923/)

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте

```
layout_alignParentRight="true"
layout_alignBottom="@id/[Ваш линеарлэйаут]"
layout_toRightOf="@id/[Ваш линеарлэйаут]"
```

Comment: Всеравно перекрывает(